# why are chart.js line graphs overlapping each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I have seen similar questions on StackOverflow, but none of the answers have helped me so far.

I am using chart.js in my web project, but now, when I want to show 2 line graphs in the same container they do weird stuff, even if I adjust the parent container or try to wrap the canvas with a div.

[image]

here is some of the code:

```html
[...]
<!--the big white container-->
<div class="Card Fill" id="5da78c0de214b0020e86f53a">
    <div class="Details">
        <span>entradas:30</span>
        <span>duracion: 0:02</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ChartContainer">
        <div class="ChartWraper">
            <canvas id="tempGraph"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="ChartWraper">
            <canvas id="ppmGraph"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
[...]
```

```js
function drawChart(canvas, datasetLabel, data, labels) {
    window[datasetLabel] = new Chart(
        document.getElementById(canvas),
        {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                datasets: [
                    {
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        label: datasetLabel,
                        fill: true,
                        data: data
                    }
                ],
                labels: labels
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    );
}


//ask api for data array
window.onload = function () {
    let droneId = document.getElementsByClassName("Card")[0].id;
    axios.get(`/api/vuelos/data/${droneId}`)
        .then((response) => {
            responseData = response.data;
            let factorized = refractor(response.data); //separate the data from the drone into arrays

            drawChart("tempGraph", "temperatura", factorized.temp, factorized.labels);
            drawChart("ppmGraph", "particulas por millon", factorized.ppm, factorized.labels);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error.message);
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

```css
.Card {
  position: relative; /* soo that i can relocate the options inside*/
  background: var(--background);
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: var(--ui-shawdow);
}
.Fill{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.Card > .Details {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: space-around;
}
.ChartContainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: space-between;
  height: 50%;
}
.ChartWraper{
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
}
canvas{
  height: 40%;
}
```

What may I be doing wrong? I have tried changing things at the CSS or the Html but does not seem to work

I want it to look moething like this, responsive withouth overflow out of the card.
[image]

Comment: you think you can do it in a snipet or a plunker? to see better how it's working

Comment: @SoulEeater here is the testing enviroment, https://volcan-col.herokuapp.com/vuelos/5da920b7f97310001760ac2a

Comment: I think your problem is with the CSS, just remove the `height: 50%` in .ChartContainer, also your whole screen has problems, I can't visualize it all in my laptop and I think it need some scroll bars..